# Predicates and quantifiers. (Discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to be sure that my answer is true.

the question is :

Let I (x) be the statement “x has an Internet connection”
and C(x, y) be the statement “x and y have chatted over
the Internet,” where the domain for the variables x and y
consists of all students in your class. Use quantiﬁers to
express each of these statements:
** Exactly one student in your class has an Internet connection.

my answer is: ∃x∀y(x=y ↔ I(y)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works.

An alternative approach would be to try to do it in two steps, and take a conjunction.

First would be "someone has internet" `exists X. I(x)` and second would be "if two people have internet then they are the same person" `forall x,y. I(x) and I(y) -> x = y`.

This way is 'simpler' in that there is less quantifier depth. Yours has a quantifier depth of two, and mine has only one.

But yours is more elegant, so YMMV.